# importing and processing data from a CSV File in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I had an pre-interview task, which I have completed and the solution works, however I was marked down and did not get an interview due to having used a TADODataset.  I basically imported a CSV file which populated the dataset, the data had to be processed in a specific way, so I used Filtering and Sorting of the dataset to make sure that the data was ordered in the way I wanted it and then I did the logic processing in a while loop.  The feedback that was received said that this was bad as it would be very slow for large files.

My main question here is if using an in memory dataset is slow for processing large files, what would have been better way to access the information from the csv file.  Should I have used String Lists or something like that?

Comment: I think you did a good job within the specs given. Large files? So use an alternative database solution that isn't memory based - your solution just scaled without changing anything else.

Comment: Thanks mj2008 I thought so at the time of writing, and also tried to write the solution in a very defensive way but considering Dorin's answer below I can now see why the interviewer would want to see this done in a different way.

Comment: I agree with @mj2008. associating `CSV` with `ADO` is a very good answer. My instinctive solution would have been the same. If you know how to handle `CSV` files with `TADODataset` surely you know how to "low-tech" read a text file line by line...

Comment: I suspect that the interviewers suffer from the "1 Smart guy who thinks all smart guys think like their 1 smart guy, and the rest are dumb guys".   It's a common industrial disease.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on how "big" and the available resources(in this case RAM) for the task.

"The feedback that was received said that this was bad as it would be very slow for large files."

CSV files are usually used for moving data around(in most cases that I've encountered files are ~1MB+ up to ~10MB, but that's not to say that others would not dump more data in CSV format) without worrying too much(if at all) about import/export since it is extremely simplistic.

Suppose you have a 80MB CSV file, now that's a file you want to process in chunks, otherwise(depending on your processing) you can eat hundreds of MB of RAM, in this case what I would do is:

```
while dataToProcess do begin
  // step1
  read <X> lines from file, where <X> is the max number of lines 
  you read in one go, if there are less lines(i.e. you're down to 50 lines and X is 100)
  to process, then you read those
  // step2
  process information
  // step3
  generate output, database inserts, etc.
end;
```

In the above case, you're not loading 80MB of data into RAM, but only a few hundred KB, and the rest you use for processing, i.e. linked lists, dynamic insert queries(batch insert), etc.

"...however I was marked down and did not get an interview due to having used a TADODataset."

I'm not surprised, they were probably looking to see if you're capable of creating algorithm(s) and provide simple solutions on the spot, but without using "ready-made" solutions.

They were probably thinking of seeing you use dynamic arrays and creating one(or more) sorting algorithm(s).

"Should I have used String Lists or something like that?"

The response might have been the same, again, I think they wanted to see how you "work".

Comment: At my office we deal every month with a 4GB+ CSV file (generated somewhere else and made available for download in zip format). Needless to say, an ADODataSet or ClientDataSet isn't a viable solution here. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dorin, using dynamic arrays and sorting algorithms just did not enter my thought process.  I guess I have been working with Ado and SQL databases for far too long, and maybe need to look at solving problems to extend my knowledge.

Comment: @KenWhite I find it a bit hard to believe that someone would create a 4GB CSV file, but that doesn't mean it's not possible, so was that a joke or? frankly never heard of more than ~100MB CSV... it's also pretty impractical...

Comment: @Mattgb I wouldn't worry that much if I were you, you've provided a fast solution, that "could" have spared quite a few "greens", if they can't appreciate that, then maybe it wasn't a good place for you, just saying...

Comment: Well, @KenWhite isn't alone in this. The software suite I work on routinely deals with files that size. And though not comma separated, they are delimited value files downloaded from a SAP system. Some are downloaded daily, some weekly, some occasionally. We also have installations where we only do delta downloads because downloading the actual files would put too large a drain on the SAP system.

Comment: @Dorin, no. Unfortunately it's absolutely true. It's a file generated by a US governmental agency that provides information on every hospital, clinic, private physician, laboratory, pharmacist (and pharmacy) and other type of medical facility in the US, and is actually more than 4GB when unzipped. They don't provide any other format that's usable by us (I think they have mainframe-type tapes or something, but they're of no use to us.)

Comment: @KenWhite So would you use the method described by Dorin above or something else, surely working with files of that sort of size is going to be a drain on resources however you process them?

Comment: @Ken, Marjan wow, that's really impressive, ever had the issue of corrupted record(s) in file due to transfer issues?

Comment: @Mattgb for files that big, you can process using multiple threads starting at different position in the file, i.e. 1 thread starts at 0 ends processing at 30%ish, 1 threads starts at 30%ish ends at 60%ish, 1 threads starts at 60%ish and ends at 100%ish(EOF), but that's just one of many ways, I want to know too how they handle files that big (:

Comment: `TFileStream` to read a line of text at a time, a quick test to see if it's one of the rows we're interested in - if not, read the next line and repeat. If it is, parse what we need out and write to a separate (temp) file. We've tried splitting it into threads to process, but this file is really bad; lines vary from a few hundred characters to several thousands (based on how many separate facility addresses they have), so splitting it is more complicated than just running through it. Once we've got our data extracted (a couple of hundred MB, usually), I have an app that consumes that data.

Comment: The final app does some validations and then does the procssing to import into our databases. @Dorin, yes; this month's file, in fact, was corrupted and caused some issues. Fortunately, the part that was corrupt was not anything we were concerned with; I modified a version of our parsing app to keep track of the last successful byte position, and then when it hit the problem area skip until it found the next set of marker data and continue processing. We were able to extract what we needed even though the file took special handling.

Comment: @Ken I may be wrong here, but reading say 32Kb at a time and increment a PChar to seek for CRLF and/or LF(to know when a records ends and another begins) would be faster than using a temporary file that needs to be processed?

Comment: Possibly. However, since it's a once-a-month process, and we run it on a utility machine that doesn't really do much else, and it's working, I don't see any need to optimize it. ;) I should say we're not reading byte-by-byte with the TFileStream - I use a 128K buffer for reading, backtrack (in memory) to the last CR/LF in that buffer, reset the stream's position to that point, and process the buffer from RAM.

Comment: (: yes... usually I get caught up into "over-engineering", oh, and sorry for not making it clear, I wasn't suggesting reading byte-by-byte, just a buffer that can be processed in memory as string. Anyhu, thank you for the info, now I won't choke when I'll hear something like: WE must parse GB's of CSV files ((:

Answer (score 1):

The interviewer was quite right.

The correct, scalable and fastest solution on any medium file upwards is to use an 'external sort'.

An 'External Sort' is a 2 stage process, the first stage being to split each file into manageable and sorted smaller files. The second stage is to merge these files back into a single sorted file which can then be processed line by line.

It is extremely efficient on any CSV file with over say 200,000 lines. The amount of memory the process runs in can be controlled and thus dangers of running out of memory can be eliminated.

I have implemented many such sort processes and in Delphi would recommend a combination of TStringList, TList and TQueue classes.

Good Luck